# How to deploy a Python 3 Flask project on Google Cloud

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, google-cloud-platform, pycharm

I have searched a lot on how to deploy a Python 3 Flask project on Google Cloud. I always end up with explanations on Python 2 or old versions for Google Cloud. The YouTube videos I have seen are at least 1 or 2 years old, and most of the services, buttons, and procedures are changed now.

I downloaded Google Cloud SDK to use it with PyCharm, but still I wasn't that lucky to get it work. Even Google docs are on Python 2 [Check this link](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/getting-started/python-standard-env). These docs are not upgraded. Could anyone help me on how to do that using PyCharm? Or at least point me to more recent docs. I appreciate any help!

Comment: Request for off-site resources are off-topic.

Comment: @jhpratt all what I want is a couple of steps. Like where should I start or how? I didn't find anything on the internet. Or couple of steps on how to do that using PyCharm! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you're using App Engine to deploy this thing, you've got an app.yaml file. The [Python Runtime page](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/runtime) on the GCP docs describes how to specify a Python version:

```
runtime: python
env: flex

runtime_config:
    python_version: 3
```

... looks like the major release number defaults to the most recent stable patch, e.g. 3 -> 3.6.4.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to use Python 3, your App Engine application should be developed in a Flexible environment (Standard only supports Python 2).

To deploy your Python 3 app, you can try this [quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/quickstart) and then adapt your code to work the same way. This supports @ingernet and his answer to configure app.yaml in a way that the app recognizes Python 3 as the language used.